# Is it possible to highlight non-query fields in Solr?

Tags: solr

When doing a query `field1:term` is it possible to get `term` hilighted in `field2`?  As an example, I've got this query which doesn't work:

`q=field1:term&hl=true&hl.fl=field2`

I do have `field2` set up properly for hilighting as the following query works:

`q=field2:term&hl=true&hl.fl=field2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can!

I must have screwed up some configuration or schema issue because it seems to be working fine now.  It seems that `field2` must be of the same type as `field1` as that seems to make it work.